# Generic data-driven unit test in MSTest

Tags: c#, generics, mstest

I tried to write a Generic Test Method in c# for data-driven unit tests with MS Test. However, this method is not shown in the Test Explorer in VS 2019.

```
        [DataRow(new int[] { 1, 3 }, new int[] { 2 }, new int[] { 1, 2, 3 })]
        [DataTestMethod]
        public void MergeTwoGenericSortedArrays_Test<T>(T[] a1, T[] a2, T[] r)
            where T : IComparable<T>
        {
            var md = new MergeSortedArrays<T>();

            T[] m = md.Merge(a1, a2);

            CollectionAssert.AreEqual(r, m);
        }
```

Is it possible to write a test like this or I should find another way?

Comment: Do you have other tests? Are they shown?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Yes, I have and they are shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A generic method cannot be a test method.
If you switch the Visual Studio Output to *"Show output from:"* **Tests** you will find some useful messages.